Docker compose : How to redirect UI container to RabbitMQ's admin page
I have a docker compose project that is composed of a frontend UI (it's blazor but I don't think it matters for this question), an ASPNetCore web API and several supporting containers like MSSql, RabbitMQ, Seg, Jaeger, etc.  Most of these supporting containers have some kind of admin page that is exposed on a certain port.
This is the section in my docker-compose.yml file for the RabbitMQ container :
#Message Queue
some.queue:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}rabbitmq:3-management
  hostname: some-queue
  networks:
    - some-network
  ports:
    - 5672:5672
    - 15672:15672
  volumes:
    - ./queue/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    - ./queue/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
  environment:
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest

When I run the project on my computer, I am able to navigate to http://localhost:15672 and see the RabbitMQ management page.  I am also able to make an admin page in my blazor frontend that has a button executing the following code :
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("http://localhost:15672");

This works beautifully on my computer, the Blazor frontend can redirect to any container's admin page as long as it's exposed like I showed above.
The issue arises when I deploy this to AWS on a Lightsail instance.  The redirection to localhost works but it redirects to MY localhost, not the lightsail instance.  How do I get the frontend to redirect to the management page exposed on the host the docker-compose project lives on?  I tried something like this and it fails (some queue being the name of the container):
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("http://some-queue:15672");

Is there a way for Blazor (or any frontend really) to be able to redirect the browser to the admin page of another container that lives in the same docker compose project?

You can't use the service name. Those only work for processes on the Docker bridge network and your Blazor app runs in a browser outside the network. You need to use an address that works from a browser.

This Lightsail instance is hidden behind Cloudfront currently and the only port that is open is 443 which redirects to port 80 of the UI container.  Are you saying the ports for the admin containers also need to be visible to the outside world for redirects to work?  Is there a way of introducing some sort of proxy container to handle this internally without needing to expose additional ports to the internet?

This is server-side blazor BTW if that makes a difference

Yes, with your current setup where they listen on different ports, all the ports that the browser needs to talk to needs to be published. If you only want a single port published, you can have a reverse proxy listen on that port and then route traffic to the different containers based on URL. So for instance http://my-domain.com/rabbitmq goes to the Rabbit MQ management page. Nginx or Traefik are popular tools for that.
